# Conversion from .m4a to .wav is not working using AudioKit Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am facing an issue using the library to convert from m4a to wav. I am using FormatConverter class, implementation of the function is correct, but the output is still m4a and it does not convert to wav.

This is the conversion code I am using, similar to the sample provided in the library.

```
            var options = FormatConverter.Options()
            options.format = "wav"
            options.sampleRate = 48000
            options.bitDepth = 24
            
            let converter = FormatConverter(inputURL: selectedFileURL, outputURL: sandboxFileURL, options: options)
            converter.start { error in
                if error == nil {
                    print("Conversion successed.")
                }
```

The file changes actually, it goes from "selectedFileURL" to "sandboxFileURL" with an increased size, the sample I am using is 76 KB, after the conversion it goes to 1.3 MB but with the same format m4a.

I am originally thinking of taking a long voice recorded using Voice Memos app, then upload it to the application and do the conversion from m4a to wav, but it stays m4a.
I uploaded two screenshots before and after the conversion from files application.

[Before the conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69MWc.png)
[After the conversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRj7t.png)

Is there something wrong I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a wav file with an m4a extension? Open a Terminal and do `file yourconvertedfile` to see the actual file format.

Comment: @EricAya As you said! It is a wave file, that is what printed in Terminal "Sample.m4a: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio".
Why it is still .m4a? The extension should automatically change after the conversion, that is the common output.

Comment: Managed to change the extension successfully. Used this line of code

                "let newURL = sandboxFileURL.deletingPathExtension().appendingPathExtension("wav")"

Thank @EricAya for youe help.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.